# RegEX : To find matching chars

Tags: regex

I have to find matching strings based on a certain condition.

An example string that i have is:

```
700PXNNEKPQ059D
```

The conditions are:

1. The string should start with "7" AND 5th character should be "Y" AND 10th character is "M" AND 11th character is "A"

   if (string[0] == "7" && (string[4] == "Y" && string[9] == "M" && string[10] == "A")
       {
           // Matched
       }
2. The string should start with "7" AND (5th character is "M" or 10th is "W")

   if (string[0] == "7" && (string[4] == "M" || string[9] == "W")
   {
       // Matched
   }

The RegEx below is what i came up with and it doesn't look good for me!

I would ideally like to come up with one RegEx that has both above conditions in it.

```
 ^7...[YW]....[M]
```

Comment: Your proposed regex bears approximately zero resemblance to the criteria in your question.  Surely you could at least *try* to solve it on your own.

Comment: Also what is the nature of the other parts of the string, only digits and/or letters ?

Comment: The string will contain alphanumeric characters and dashes "-"

Comment: In your regex there's a `X` and a `P`, what are these since you don't mention them in your conditions? also the string sample you gave doesnt fit any of the conditions... please correct your post

Comment: You should look into the `|` regex operator for expressing pattern alternatives longer than a single character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^7.{3}[MY].{4}[MW]A
```

It matches all your criteria.

**Edit:** If you strictly want to match the criteria you can use

```
(^7.{3}Y.{4}WA)|(^7.{3}M.{5})|(^7.{8}W)
```

Comment: You can make that even shorter... `(^7.{3}Y.{4}WA)|(^7.{3}M.{5})|(^7.{8}W)`